# Toucan Backup Regex for Specific Extensions?

Tags: regex, file-extension

I'm using Toucan Backup to encrypt files (like tax documents) in my cloud service storage. Running into some issues though:

I tried using the following regex:

```
\.(pdf|docx|doc|xls|xlsx|txt|xls)$
```

With an inclusion rule, but it also included other extensions other than that.  I also tried a simple filter to exclude `*` files after the initial rule but that got interpreted and excluded the files I wanted to encrypt.

Is there a regex that can be used as an exclusion rule that will flag all extensions EXCEPT ones listed? Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Watch out for a pretty basic regex error: the dot matches *anything*. Escape it to match just the dot, as you surely intended.

Comment: What about `file.php.txt`?